# ِِِAn error occurred during installation: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r36.zip': SSL peer

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu

I have installed Android Studio I got that problem every time I do updates or download anything.

always download fails, what can I to do?

[image: SDK Installation]